# How to find correct Hashbang or Shebang for PHP script

Tags: php, shebang, hashbang

I have set up a [forwarder](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Forwarders) in my cPanel so that any emails that go to contact@mydomain.com will be picked up and processed by a PHP script.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$body = '';
while( !feof($fd) ){
    $body .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

//----doing my tasks, for example:--
mail('self@myAnotherDomain.com', 'Test Subject', $body);

?>
```

I will have to run almost the same solution for my multiple clients with various types of cPanel providers. My problem is with the first line which is called [Hashbang or Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). From web I found that the following shebangs are valid based on the PHP versions:

```
For PHP 5.2.x the shebang would be "#!/usr/bin/php"
For PHP 5.3.x the shebang would be "#!/usr/bin/php53"
//My test server is running with PHP 5.5 at this moment and "#!/usr/bin/php" works fine.
```

Again, some says, `#!/usr/local/bin/php` or `#!/usr/local/lib/php`, etc.

**My question:** Is there any way to find correct hashbang properly/directly/easily for different cPanel environments like [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) or using any coding or from any configuration files?

Answer (score 4):

To make your script portable, try using this instead,

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

This simply searches for an executable named `php` in your `$PATH`. This will work in like >95% of cases. If you find a system that it doesn't work on, then just manually find where PHP is installed and modify that one script.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski To my mind the OP was asking how to identify the install directory of PHP on different systems with different install paths, so his script will function correctly wherever it is installed (portability). My answer is the solution to this. Not sure why the down votes.

Comment: perhaps because of something like that `$ /usr/bin/env php` -> `/usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory`. Far from portable solution, unless it's documented this works with cPanel environments

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski All this shebang does is look for an executable name php in your `$PATH`. It won't work when the PHP location is not in your path. I have no idea in what strange set of circumstances that would occur. This will work in like 95% of cases I would guess. Let me update my answer to reflect this

Comment: However, I'm going to downvote it because it doesn't answer the question. It sidesteps the question. The answer might be "There isn't a way, but this works in 95% of cases," but as it stands this doesn't answer how to *find the correct* hashbang, which is needed in the other 5% anyway.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Seems a bit harsh. So if questions are posted on SO that aren't technically possible to provide an answer to, all answers attempting to provide a workaround or partial solution to help the OP should get down-voted because they don't "answer the question" as asked? You must have fun all day on here...

Comment: No: I don't think you have read my comment. I address that point.

Comment: So you're saying that if I had put the phrase "There isn't a way", before my comment of "This will work in like >95% of cases", you would not have down-voted it?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'd argue that for the remaining 5%, PHP is incorrectly installed on their system: it may be located in /home/fred/banana, or /usr/local/bin/fsck, or as the OP's question suggests, they may have 47 different copies installed in /usr/bin/phpNN, and trying to wildly guess which is correct would be inappropriate. Correctly installing and configuring PHP so that it is in your path as "php" is a separate question, and likely out of the scope of Stack Overflow. Possibly the sysadmin SE?

Comment: This answer is the only and unique and possible way if it needs to be done in the shebang. In command line you would do `which php` but this is not possible within the shebang. Moreover if you cannot easily determinate the correct binary's path it's not because a server server misconfiguration! As an example in cPanel would be "/opt/cpanel/ea-phpDD/root/usr/bin" but if the same server have cagefs and alt-php enabled for "some" users it would be "/opt/cloudlinux/alt-phpDD/root/usr/bin".

Comment: In those system you would search "/usr/local/bin/" but different environments and operative systems requires different binaries to be used, eg: php-cli, php-cgi and others... "/usr/bin/env php" is the only one knowing which one to use.